# Use git to get SHA-1 of repo

Tags: python, beginner, git, child-process

I've created the function below to get the SHA-1 of the repository used by my CI server. The hash is then used to update the pass/fail status of the commit on GitHub.

I'm a python amateur. What stands out below?

```
def get_sha():
    root = os.environ["PWD"]
    repodir = os.listdir(root)[0]
    # /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/6490b1f573dca4e4e0d988197ae6c225/Source/repo_name
    repo = os.path.join(root, repodir)
    sha = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD'], cwd=repo).decode('ascii').strip()
    return sha
```

Please advise on best practices, errors this might encounter, values I should be checking, etc.

**EDIT:**

Based on feedback I have revised it to the following:

```
def get_sha():
    for subdir in os.listdir('.'):
        if is_git_directory(subdir):
            return get_repo_sha(subdir)
    assert False

def is_git_directory(path = '.'):
    return subprocess.call(['git', '-C', path, 'status'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')) == 0    

def get_repo_sha(repo):
    sha = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD'], cwd=repo).decode('ascii').strip()
    return sha
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me that this would be equivalent but shorter:

```
def get_sha():
    repo = os.listdir('.')[0]
    sha = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD'], cwd=repo).decode('ascii').strip()
    return sha
```

Because, `.` is essentially the same as `os.environ['PWD']`,
with the difference that it's not an absolute path.
Since `subprocess.check_output(..., cwd=...)` works fine with relative paths too,
I don't see the reason to use an absolute path, and so no need for `PWD`.

But more importantly,
I find it a bit odd that this script assumes that the first entry in the directory listing is a Git repository.
This setup seems a bit fragile.
It would be better to pass the repo path as a parameter to this function:

```
def get_sha(repo):
    sha = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD'], cwd=repo).decode('ascii').strip()
    return sha
```

Then you'd have something simple, clear, no questions asked.

Comment: I agree that I don't like the fragile `[0]` to access the directory. I'd probably do a loop to look for a git repo, but due to learning syntax, etc., I haven't yet. Tips on best python way to do so?

Comment: A simple `for subdir in os.listdir('.'): ...` should do. And then, before calling `get_sha(repo)`, it will be good to add another helper function to check that the directory is indeed a Git working tree (should contain `.git` subdirectory). Your more complete program could be a good topic for another question here on Code Review.

Comment: Thanks. I've revised my question with the latest, including searching all available subdirectories and checking if it's actually a git repo.

Answer (score 5):

Since Janos already gave a nice review on the actual workings of the code, I'll just add some nitpicks:

- The [python style-guide (PEP-8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) defines the maximum line-length to be 79 characters for code (and 72 for docstrings). Your sha-"calculation" line is 93 characters of code (and another 4 for indentation)
- Your original code is only executable on linux (well POSIX systems, but alas), since pwd is a linux thing. IIRC there's quite a bunch of CI servers that are actually also running on windows. The change proposed by janos is also perfectly fine for windows systems.
- There is no docstring: I strongly suggest you document the function some more. There are assumptions made in the function that should be in the docstring (what directory can this be executed in, what does this return, ...).

The "final code" incorporating the changes suggested by janos is as follows:

```
def get_sha(repo):
    """
    Grabs the current SHA-1 hash of the given directory's git HEAD-revision.
    The output of this is equivalent to calling git rev-parse HEAD.

    Be aware that a missing git repository will make this return an error message, 
    which is not a valid hash.
    """
    sha = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD'], cwd=repo)
    return sha.decode('ascii').strip()
```

Comment: Nice to see you reviewing Python! (and we do need more Python reviewers, to cut down on the [notoriously high number of unanswered questions](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=unanswered))

Comment: > "the call to strip should actually be superfluous" <

When I print `sha` without `strip()` [it looks like this](http://i.imgur.com/tKew5qz.png), so idk...

Comment: Also, passing the unstripped SHA to the github API complains: `422 No commit found for SHA`

Comment: hmm.. I can't even get this to run properly on my machine, so I can't check against that, but your SHA-1 looks rather very short. additionally `strip()` as per documentation solely removes spaces on both sides of the string

Comment: @pkamb okay I got it working now. I cannot find a difference in between the stripped and the non-stripped version. I did have to add shell=True to the `check_output` arguments, but that shouldn't affect the output so much. Overall I still think that strip() is actually superfluous and thus should be removed ;)

Comment: nevermind I actuall found a difference... there is a newline coming from check_output. It will be removed when stripped. I'll remove that part from my answer

Comment: Yeah, the SHA in the image was shortened by the screenshot, sorry for the confusion.